# Spelling error when trying to import imutils

Tags: python, ubuntu, imutils

I'm running Python 3.7.1 and have Imutils 0.5.2 installed correctly on Ubuntu 18.04.

I'm trying to import imutils as shown below:

```
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils.video import FPS
import numpy as np 
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2
```

However, when it comes to launching the code I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "real_time_object_detection.py", line 3, in <module>
    from imultils.video import FPS
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imultils'
```

Notice that Python (?) has added an 'l' into imutils making it imuLtils!
Which I am guessing is why the code will not run, if it's trying to open the module!

I've rewritten the code, restarted, uninstalled and reinstalled imutils!

Why is it doing this!? and how can I stop it from doing this?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You get the error just from running the import statements above? No other code below that might be referencing `imutils` incorrectly spelled as `imultils`?

Comment: Looks like it's misspelled in the `real_time_object_detection.py` script. Is that yours?

Comment: @gbeaven no! I've gone through the whole of the damn script several times.

Comment: It looks like you are using an example off Pyimagesearch maybe follow  the tutorial for his stuff below: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/18/real-time-object-detection-with-deep-learning-and-opencv/